# How can handle RabbitMQ consumer timeout in NestJS

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ as message broker between my Rest API GW and microservices.

```js
    {
      provide: 'MY-MICROSERVICE',
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const user = configService.get('RABBITMQ_USER');
        const password = configService.get('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD');
        const host = configService.get('RABBITMQ_HOST');
        const queue = configService.get('RABBITMQ_MY_QUEUE');
        return ClientProxyFactory.create({
          transport: Transport.RMQ,
          options: {
            urls: [`amqp://${user}:${password}@${host}`],
            queue,
            queueOptions: {
              durable: true,
            },
            noAck: true,
          },
        });
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
```

When using req/response method `MessagePattern`, I need to set a timeout If the consumer not being available for any reason.

Is it possible?

Currently, my REST endpoint getting Timed out, and all things getting queued, and when a consumer gets back to work it processes all of them.

Answer (score 1):

**I have found only two options**

### First Method:

Set your queue setting with `'x-messsage-ttl'` to 0, this will keep the message only if a consumer is available.

```
ClientsModule.register([
  {
    name: 'TEST_SERVICE',
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [rabbitmqConfigUrl],
      queue: 'TEST_QUEUE',
      queueOptions: {
        durable: false,
        arguments: {
          'x-message-ttl': 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
]),
```

### Second Method:

Per each message you are sending from the client, add message header.

> expiration='0'

This is better as you have control per each message incase the service has messages that doesn't expire

```
 const config = new RmqRecordBuilder(PATTERN)
        .setOptions({
          expiration: '0',
        })
        .build();

      const response: any = await lastValueFrom(
        this.client.send(QUEUENAME, config).pipe(timeout(300)),
      );
```